# RDLC, Custom Code, GAC & Shared Hosting Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a web application that is hosted in a shared environment.
This applicatin uses RDLC reports and I need to use a custom (strongly named) DLL in the report.
Now, it looks like this DLL needs to be GAC deployed but I have no access to the shared server's GAC.
All I can do i bin deploy.

Is there a way to use custom code DLL in RDLC without GAC deplyoing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tehre is - but being shares hosting you also ahve no access to the security configuration so effectiely: no, there is not. Shared hosting is very limtied and you should haev made sure your application works under recommended IIS configurations (visible at http://www.iis.net/, maintanied by microsoft) for hosters from the beginning.

Comment: And, beside the shared hosting limitation, what would be the alternative configurato ti implement in order not to GAC deploy?

Comment: Not use this particular report technology. SImple like that - there are alternative report technologies that do not use GAC. RDLC is written t orequire installation. Can not install - do not use it.